# A way to test if processes running inside docker are on the same host

Tags: docker

Let's say I have two processes running C++ code inside docker (separate images) on a single machine/host.

How can I figure out if these processes are sharing the same host machine or not (by writing C++ code / Linux commands, that runs inside the container).

EDIT

[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) mentioned adding this information from the outside and "help the container" with more insights but I'm looking for ways to do so from the inside without access to the Dockerfile and/or docker launch environment.

Comment: Would your problem be solved using affinity parameters to a container orchestration engine (like swarm, kubernetes or Mesos). Instruct that your containers should be deployed separately from each other and let the engine do the rest

Comment: i'm looking for ways independent from docker/orchestrations. i'll edit the question to emphasize

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [issues 1143](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-77088168), maybe you can check the host ip. If it is the same in both containers, there should be running on the same host.

> Note: Sometimes you need to connect to the Docker host, which means getting the IP address of the host.
>   You can use the following shell commands to simplify this process:

```
$ alias hostip="ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | grep -Eo 'via \S+' | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
$ docker run --add-host=docker:$(hostip) --rm -it debian
```

---

The other option is to [pass the docker host when running the container](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-133853817):

> When you're doing docker run, add the following parameter: `--add-host=dockerhost:replace_with_docker_host_ip`, which creates an entry in the container's `/etc/hosts` file.
>   Which, of course, means that you can refer to your docker host from within that container using its name, `dockerhost`.

See "[Adding entries to a container hosts file](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/#adding-entries-to-a-container-hosts-file)"

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for ways independent from outside additions. i'll edit the question to emphasize